# Capture groups in switch statement

Tags: javascript, regex, coffeescript, switch-statement

I am trying to match a string within a `switch` block. The matching and branching part works fine, but I need a way to retrieve the capture groups on a match.

Is there a way to do this at all? How?

```
switch
  when str.match /f(o+)bar/ then something # I need the capture group here
  when str.match /hasta la (vista|pasta)/ then something_else # or here
```

Comment: What does that look like in the resulting JavaScript?

Comment: The code doesn't look like it will work when it is compiled to JS: [Demo](http://coffeescript.org/#try:switch%20someString%0A%20%20when%20%2Ff(o%2B)bar%2F%20then%20%20%23%0A%20%20when%20%2Fhasta%20la%20(vista%7Cpasta)%2F%20then%20%23). Did you compile it somewhere else or am I missing some necessary context?

Comment: @gyre agreed — it'll "work" in that it won't cause an error, but it won't compare the string to the regexes in the intended way. The comparisons are `===` comparisons I think, so it'll be checking to see if the string "is" each regex object (and of course it will be none of them).

Comment: @gyre there should be some code where the ellipsis `…` is but that's the part I'm asking about. put a dummy expression in there and it compiles ok.

Comment: @edgerunner [Still not working for me.](http://coffeescript.org/#try:switch%20someString%0A%20%20when%20%2Ff(o%2B)bar%2F%20then%20%20console.log(%27hi%27)%0A%20%20when%20%2Fhasta%20la%20(vista%7Cpasta)%2F%20then%20console.log(%27sup%27)) The code won't do as you intend; it compares the string to the regular expression by identity (not matching).

Comment: Damn, looks like this is a ruby-only thing after all. :( I'll have to do it the ugly way. Edit coming in a moment

Comment: Still the same question though…

Comment: @gyre, thanks. I was gnawing on the wrong end of the bone for so long. It became crystal clear after you pointed out the problem.

Comment: @edgerunner I added another possibility for you if you'd like to check it out

Comment: @gyre much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also define utility functions `matching` and `matches` to make the `when` cases look a little cleaner:

```
# Definitions
match = string = null

matching = (s) ->
   string = s
   true

matches = (re) -> (match = re.exec string) != null

# Usage:
switch matching 'hasta la pasta'
  when matches /f(o+)bar/ then console.log match
  when matches /hasta la (vista|pasta)/ then console.log match
```

Answer (score 0):

I should have figured out sooner. It is possible to make an assignment in a `when` statement, which can then be used as is

```
switch
  when mtch = str.match /f(o+)bar/ then something(mtch[1].length)
  when mtch = str.match /hasta la (vista|pasta)/ then something_else(mtch[0])
```

Works as intended, as I can access the match results in `mtch` as usual.